# Can generator be used more than once?

Tags: python, generator, yield-keyword

This is my piece of code with two generators defined:

```
one_line_gen = (x for x in range(3))

def three_line_gen():
    yield 0
    yield 1
    yield 2
```

When I execute:

```
for x in one_line_gen:
    print x

for x in one_line_gen:
    print x
```

The result is as expected:

```
0
1
2
```

However, if I execute:

```
for x in three_line_gen():
    print x

for x in three_line_gen():
    print x
```

The result is:

```
0
1
2
0
1
2
```

Why? I thought any generator can be used only once.

Comment: Don't confuse a generator **function** with the generator it produces.

Comment: Put differently, if you used `def one_line_gen(): return (x for x in range(3))`, your first example would be equivalent (producing a generator every time you called the function).

Comment: Closely related: [Generator Expression vs yield: Why isn't 'next()' working?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10958771)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`three_line_gen` is not a generator, it's a function. What it returns when you call it is a generator, a brand new one each time you call it. Each time you put parenthesis like this:

```
three_line_gen()
```

It is a brand new generator to be iterated on. If however you were to first do

```
mygen = three_line_gen()
```

and iterate over `mygen` twice, the second time will fail as you expect.

Answer (score 8):

no, you can not iterate over a generator twice. a generator is exhausted once you have iterated over it. you may make a copy of a generator with [`tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) though:

```
from itertools import tee

one_line_gen = (x for x in range(3))
gen1, gen2 = tee(one_line_gen)
# or: 
# gen1, gen2 = tee(x for x in range(3))

for item in gen1:
    print(item)

for item in gen2:
    print(item)
```

for the other issues see [Ofer Sadan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45400058/4954037).

Answer (score 2):

> Why? I thought any generator can be used only once.

Because every call to *three_line_gen()* creates a new generator.

Otherwise, you're correct that generators only run forward until exhausted.

> Can generator be used more than once?

Yes, it is possible if the results are buffered outside the generator.  One easy way is to use [*itertools.tee()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

```
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> def three_line_gen():
        yield 0
        yield 1
        yield 2

>>> t1, t2 = tee(three_line_gen())
>>> next(t1)
0
>>> next(t2)
0
>>> list(t1)
[1, 2]
>>> list(t2)
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, generator can be used only once. but you have **two** generator object.

```
# Python 3


def three_line_gen():
    yield 0
    yield 1
    yield 2

iterator = three_line_gen()
print(iterator)
for x in iterator:
    print(id(iterator), x)

iterator2 = three_line_gen()
print(iterator2)
for x in iterator2:
    print(id(iterator2), x)
```

And the result is:

```
<generator object three_line_gen at 0x1020401b0>
4328784304 0
4328784304 1
4328784304 2
<generator object three_line_gen at 0x1020401f8>
4328784376 0
4328784376 1
4328784376 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in One liner is `Generator` Object while the three liner is a `function`.
They meant to be different.

These two are similar.

```
def three_line_gen_fun():
    yield 0
    yield 1
    yield 2

three_line_gen = three_line_gen_fun()
one_line_gen = (x for x in range(3))

type(three_line_gen) == type(one_line_gen)
```